# opentok.bundle is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, opentok

I am trying to run [TokBox sample app](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World).

It has one file missing - `opentok.bundle`.

I read in [forum](http://tokbox.com/forums/ios/opentok-bundle-build-failure-on-hello-world-resolved-t15239) that:

```
Then, I dragged the opentok.bundle bundle from the 
Opentok.framework/Versions/A/Resources subdirectory
of the OpenTok iOS SDK via the finder
```

But how do I get open the framework file?

Comment: you dont have access to framework source code...its built-in already

Comment: .bundle is not a framework, it's a folder. Right click > Show package contents

Comment: @preetam, if you'll open the sample app, you'll see opentok.bundle is missing. And adding openbox framework didn't help. I read forums and they say to add the bundle manually after taking it from framework in Finder.

Comment: @Desdenova, I do not have the bundle. I have only the framework. I am trying to extract the bundle from the framework like the forum sais

Comment: Did you do this? `Important: Be sure to use git clone --recursive [URL] to grab the required OpenTok iOS SDK submodule!`

Comment: @Desdenova I've cloned it directly from github without terminal

Comment: @Desdenova OMG It did work now. I should have cloned in the first place and not download as a zip. Put this as a answer. I will check it

Comment: Na, no need. I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, humble [Desdenova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771231/desdenova) for the help:
What helped me was, cloning the project instead of downloading zip file from GitHub.